# Issue with update content data in handsontable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, handsontable

I'm trying to implement `handsontable`. As per my requirement, I want to re-render `handsontable` from changing a dropdown value, but on dropdown selection, the `handsontable` does not update properly. Below is my code:

*Handsontable.vue:*

```
<template>
  <div id="hot-preview">
    <HotTable :settings="settings" :ref="referenceId"></HotTable>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { HotTable } from '@handsontable-pro/vue';

export default {
  components: {
    HotTable
  },
  props: ['settings', 'referenceId'],
}
</script>

<style>
#hot-preview {
  max-width: 1050px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

*Parent component*:

```
<template>
  <div id="provisioning-app">
    <v-container grid-list-xl fluid>
      <v-select
          :items="selectList"
          item-text="elementName"
          item-value="elementName"
          label="Standard"
          v-model="selected"></v-select>
        <handsontable :settings.sync="settings" :referenceId="referenceId"></handsontable>
     </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Handsontable from '@/components/Handsontable';
import PrevisioningService from '@/services/api/PrevisioningService';

export default {
  components: {
    Handsontable
  },
  data: () => ({
    selectList: [],
    selectApp: [],
    selectedOption: '',
    referenceId: 'provision-table',
  }),

  created(){
    PrevisioningService.getProvisioningList(this.$session.get('userId'), this.$session.get('customerId')).then(response => {
      this.provisioningList = response;
    });
  },

  beforeUpdate() {
    this.provisioningApp = this.getProvisioningAppList;
  },
  computed: {
    settings () {
      return {
          data: this.getSelectApp,
          colHeaders: ["Data Uploaded on", "Duration in Minutes", "Start Time", "Shift","Description","Next Day Spill Over", "Site Name"],
          columns: [
            {type: 'text'},
            {type: 'text'},
            {type: 'text'},
            {type: 'text'},
            {type: 'text'},
            {type: 'text'},
            {type: 'text'}
          ],
          rowHeaders: true,
          dropdownMenu: true,
          filters: true,
          rowHeaders: true,
          search: true,
          columnSorting: true,
          manualRowMove: true,
          manualColumnMove: true,
          contextMenu: true,
          afterChange: function (change, source) {
            alert("after change");
          },
          beforeUpdate: function (change, source) {
            alert("before update");
          }
        }
    },

    getSelectApp () {
      if(this.selectedOption !== undefined && this.selectedOption !== null && this.selectedOption !== ''){
        PrevisioningService.getProvisioningAppList(this.selectedOption, this.$session.get('userId'), this.$session.get('customerId')).then(response => {
          this.provisioningApp = response;
          return this.provisioningApp;
        });
      }
    }
  },
  method: {
    getSelected () {
      return this.selectedOption;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

With the above code, my data is received successfully from the server, but I'm unable to update the data in `handsontable`, as shown in the following screenshots:

[image: Here how to show Handsontable when No any value selected on drop-down]

[image: And 2nd image show how the table looks after change dropdown value]

How do I properly render the table after the dropdown selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues:

- `handsontable` appears to not handle dynamic `settings` (see [console errors](https://jsfiddle.net/308gx5bk/)), so `settings` should not be a computed property. Since the only settings property that needs to be updated is `settings.data`, that property alone should be mutated (i.e., don't reset the value of `settings`).

  To address this, move `settings` into `data()`, initializing `settings.data` to `null` so that it would still be reactive:

  ```
   data() {
     settings: {
       data: null,
       colHeaders: [...],
       ...
     }
   },
   computed: {
     // settings() { }  // DELETE THIS
   }
  ```
- `getSelectApp` is a computed property that is incorrectly asynchronous (i.e., in this case, it fetches data and handles the response later). A computed property cannot be asynchronous, so this computed property actually returns `undefined`. While there is a `return` call inside the computed property, the return does not set the value of the computed property because it's inside a [`Promise` callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

  ```
   PrevisioningService.getProvisioningAppList(/*...*/).then(response => {
     this.provisioningApp = response;
     return this.provisioningApp; // DOES NOT SET COMPUTED PROPERTY VALUE
   });
  ```

Also note the [side effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458203/simple-vue-js-computed-properties-clarification) from `this.provisioningApp = response`. It doesn't seem `this.provisionApp` is needed in this code in any case, so it should be removed as clean-up.

It seems the intention of this computed property is to update `settings.data` based on the value of the selected option. To accomplish that, you would have to use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on `selectedOption`, which would change `settings.data`.

```
    watch: {
      selectedOption(val) {
        PrevisioningService.getProvisioningAppList(/*...*/).then(response => {
          this.settings.data = response;
        });
      }
    },
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rr02q7137p)